# UIImageView wrongly located when animating

Tags: swift, uiviewanimation

I'm just trying to do a small carrousel with UIImageView and something weird is happening when I add the second image. Starting with only 1 image I just want to send it to the left, so I just do the following code that works perfectly fine, I mean, the image goes to the left as expected.

```
        let frame = self.mainImage.frame
        var newFrame = frame

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.9, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.mainImage.frame.origin.x = 0 - frame.size.width

            }, completion: { (done) -> Void in
                if done {
                     self.mainImage.frame = frame
                }
            }
        )
```

However when I add a the second image both image comes from the right. Maybe it is something very easy but I can't see what is going on.

```
        let frame = self.mainImage.frame
        var newFrame = frame
        newFrame.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width + 50

        let newImageView = UIImageView(frame: newFrame)
        newImageView.image = UIImage(named: "C2")
        newImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        self.view.addSubview(newImageView)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.9, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.mainImage.frame.origin.x = 0 - frame.size.width
            newImageView.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)
            }, completion: { (done) -> Void in
                if done {
                    self.mainImage.frame = frame
                    newImageView.removeFromSuperview()
                }
            }
        )
```